# Activity Destroyed when Started another application from it

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments, android-activity

I have implemented activity with multiple fragments, from one fragment I am generating pdf file and to view that I am opening pdf reader(Adope pdf reader), but when I back from pdf reader my application's activity restart.. how to stop that thing..

here is the code by which I am starting pdf reader

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
  intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file),"application/pdf");
  intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
  context.startActivity(intent);
```

and here the actvity life stack of my app

activity's onpause called

fragments onsave called

activity's onsave called

activity's onstop called

activity's onDestroy called

activity's onstart called

activity's onRestoreInstanceStat called

activity's onPause called

activity's onsave called

activity's onstop called

activity's onDestroy called

activity's onstart called

activity's onRestoreInstanceState called

here is manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.example.project"
 android:versionCode="1"
 android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19"
    />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="false"
              android:normalScreens="false"
              android:largeScreens="false"
              android:xlargeScreens="true"
                android:anyDensity="true"
              android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600"
           />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:name=".ApplicationClass"

     >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.project.LoginScreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.project.General"
        android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.general" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Does your activity has any specific flags (from Manifest or Intent code)?

Comment: Any. That could mess up the activity as you describe it. Btw, by "restart" you mean it goes into `onCreate()` again right?

Comment: it is a tablet app, so I have added android:screenOrientation="landscape" for each activity

Comment: you can't really. once your application is in the background, it can be killed at any time. you have to save/restore the state. see http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html

Comment: Have you looked in the logcat to see if there are any errors? Don't filter the logcat because you might miss something important.

Comment: no any error... just activity restarts

Comment: Please try to remove `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY` when starting the pdf reader and see if that helps.

Comment: got my problem and solved it... thanks to all for responding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That problem was occurring due to orientation change of Activities.
I just added following line to the activity in manifest.xml and that solved my problem...

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```